# Is there a way to fit missing values in rows by comparing distances to other rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data

I have a database where some rows contain `?` instead of a number, sometimes more than one.
I'm trying to figure out a way to maybe fill that value by running a euclidean distance comparison of that row to the other rows and replacing `?` with the corresponding value in the closest row. (Rather than doing something like forward filling or with mean or median)
I'm not entirely sure where to start. I guess I could either drop the entire column with `?` for that particular row and try to compare distances using the remaining numerical values, but there will certainly be other rows containing `?` in a different place, so I would have to either drop those columns too, or just compare to the rows that are missing values in the same column.
Or maybe there already exists some kind of module for doing something like that.
Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is knn-Imputation. Some R packages already exist for that, and I am sure Python implementations will also be available. Or you could try hot-deck imputation, which imputes a missing value based on a random draw from other similar observations.

My personal advice would be to go for MICE imputation if possible. Much better than the alternatives suggested especially to avoid introducing bias in parameter estimates.

Comment: numpy's masked array can help filling missing values https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#examples